# Django Rest Framework filtering a many to many field

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I would like to filter a serialization of a many to many field, but I don't need to create a view or a generic view as explained [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) because I need to use the data in another view.

The code is pretty simple. The *locations* in the model si a manytomany field.

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = LocationSerializer(many=True)
    # [...]
    class Meta:
        model = Service
```

And the LocationSerializer is:

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # [...]
    class Meta:
        model = LocationAddress
        # [...]
```

I would like to get the locations serialized but only based on a boolean field in the model. *active=True*. How I can do that?

Comment: Are you saying that you only want Locations with active=True to be serialized, or that you only want the active field of a location to be serialized?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the `locations` field within the serializer to be writable, you may benefit from just dropping to a `SerializerMethodField`. The other option is to dynamically remove the `locations` field when you are serializing an individual object, which will create inconsistent output if multiple objects are returned that do not have the same `active` flag.

To do it with a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield), you would just add a new method on the `ServiceSerializer`.

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = SerializerMethodField("get_locations")
    # [...]
    class Meta:
        model = Service

    def get_locations(self, obj):
        if obj.active:
            return LocationSerializer(obj.locations.all(), many=True)

        return None
```

This will make `locations` read-only, which may not be what you are hoping for. It will also means that `locations` will return `null` when it's not active, and you may have been looking to remove the key entirely.

The other option is to just drop the key entirely in the `to_representation` (`to_native` in DRF 2.x) method.

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locations = LocationSerializer(many=True)
    # [...]
    class Meta:
        model = Service

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        rep = super(ServiceSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

        del rep["locations"]

        return rep
```

Comment: `return LocationSerializer(obj.locations.all(), many=True)` will give you `SerializerMethodField() is not JSON serializable` so you should use `LocationSerializer(obj.locations.all(), many=True).data`